# Angular JS directives with ng-repeat failing to loop through child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, accordion

I'm developing a small solution using AngularJS (i'm new to it) and i'm trying to create an **accordion** effect using  `<dl> <dt> <dd>` tags. I have defined a `ng-repeat` to create both the dt and dd inside the dl from a .json file and it works well.

My problem comes up when i want to add some functionality through a directive, so i can show/hide the `<dd>` element by clicking on the `<dt>` element. My directive's code appears not to be working, as it doesn't really do what i'm expecting -it doesn't do anything-. **Maybe** the directive tries to add the functionality before the `ng-repeat` has finished it's process? but for this I have added the $timeout variable.

whole solution: http://codepen.io/valecarlos/pen/PNdpeZ

**Directive code:**

```
app.directive('accordion', function($timeout){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<dl ng-transclude></dl>',
    link: function(scope,element){
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log(element)
            console.log(element.children().length);//this gives me 0

            console.log("im here" + element)
            element.children().find('dd').css('display','none');
            element.find('dt').on('click', function(event){
                element.children().find("dd").css('display', 'none')
                var ddToOpen = angular.element(event.target).next();
                ddToOpen.css('display','block');
            });
        });
    }
};
});
```

HTML:

```
<accordion>
            <dt ng-repeat-start="article in articles">
                //my content
            </dt>
            <dd ng-repeat-end="">
                //my content
            </dd>
<accordion>
```

**note:** I tried to implement this accordion using both jquery and AngularJS but nothing would happen when i clicked the `dt` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is (as shown in the pen) that you are loading the data asynchronously and not waiting for the promise to resolve. This is what I mean:

```
$http.get('http://www.carlosvalencia.co/news_mock.json').success(function(data) {
    //$timeout and the DOM stuff will be long gone when we get here :(
    $scope.articles = data;
});
```

Sure, using `$timeout` will wait until angular has finished doing its template rendering stuff, but it won't wait for your data to load. When the DOM manipulation gets done, there are no articles to list and thus no elements to find.

Now what you'd need to do is somehow tell your directive to delay doing its thing until the data is ready. I don't have a clear fits-for-all-purposes solution for doing this. Angular provides several methods for communication between components and they all work well for some purposes but might not be good for others. The easiest thing to do here, for example, might be just using [scope.$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to tell the directive that everything is ready.

That's not probably the best solution, though, as events can create quite subtle dependencies between components. Rather, I'd explicitly ask for the promise in the accordion directive, so that the parent controller can dictate when we are ready to roll. So I'd add

```
scope: {
    promise: '&?'  //Ask for an optional promise getter from the parent template
}
template: '<dl ng-transclude></dl>',
link: function(scope,element){

    //We'll either wait for the given promise or default to a resolved promise
    var promise = scope.promise ? scope.promise() : $q.resolve();

    //Wait for both that promise AND the additional $timeout before doing DOM stuff
    promise.then($timeout).then(function() {
        console.log(element)
        console.log(element.children().length);//shouldn't be 0 anymore
        //... the DOM stuff
    });
}
```

And now we'll just need to pass the $http promise from the parent controller.

```
$scope.promise = $http.get('http://www.carlosvalencia.co/news_mock.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.articles = data;
});
```

And use that when using the accordion directive

```
<accordion promise="promise" >
        <dt ng-repeat-start="article in articles">
        ...
```

[Here's a working solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdPgrb).
(Note that I had to replace the `$http` method with something else for testing, you should be just fine with $http)

---

**Update:** You also need to replace all the `element.children().find(selector)` calls with `element.find(selector)` to find the elements. I've updated the pen to cover that.

Comment: Thanks noppa! I understand now where i'm failing, i've been trying to implement what you've suggested but i haven't been able to get it working, and checking your codepen, does it hide the `dd` when it loads? it doesn't seem to work for me. cheers!

Comment: You're right, there was a separate issue with the selectors. I updated the answer and the pen and it should work now.